# Comparing two fields of different models without using foreign key in django

Tags: python, django, filter, foreign-keys, crm

This is regarding CRM software.

I have two models `profile_candidate` and `Agent`,
`profile_candidate` contains some 20 fields and `Reference_Mobile` is one of them.
`Agent` is the model which contains the names of all the users who work as agents with the field name user.

Here what I need to do is...

I need to compare the field `Reference_Mobile` of each `profile_candidate` with all the users available in Agent model, and I need to retrieve the objects of `profile_candidate(model)` where the `Reference_Mobile` is not matching with any of the users in the Agent Model.

Note: Without using foreign key for `Reference_Mobile` field from the Agent model, because I cannot display all the users to the candidates while filling the form of `profile_candidate`.

This is the problem I have been facing for the last two days, I am beginner of Django and python too.

I also tried many other different ways but I could not find the proper output.

I hope I explained clearly the problem.
Please anyone help me out in achieving this..

my `views.py`:

```
def lead_unassigned(request):
    team_values = profile_candidate.objects.exclude(Reference_Mobile = Agent.user)

    return render(request, 'leads/lead_list_unassigned.html', 
    {'team_values':team_values})
```

Thanking you in Advance,
Dinesh Babu

Answer (score 0):

If the `Reference_Mobile` field of the `profile_candidate` model is not the same object type as `Agent.user` then the exclude will not be able to compare the two accurately. Double check that the model field types are the same, if they are not then you may be comparing a sub-field within `Reference_Mobile`, like a username or other type.

Comment: Both are same type of fields